# In ElasticSearch, how does sort interact with function_score?

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

See my search query below with specific questions further down.

```
search = {
    'query' : {
        'function_score': {
            'score_mode': 'multiply'                                                                                                                                
            'functions': functions,
            'query': {
                'match_all':{}
                },
            'filter': {
                'bool': {
                    'must': filters_include,
                    'must_not': filters_exclude
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    'sort': [{'_score': {'order': 'desc'}},
             {'time': {'order': 'desc'}}]
    }
```

where `functions` look like:

```
[{'weight': 5.0, 'gauss': {'time': {'scale': '7d'}}}, 
 {'weight': 3.0, 'script_score': {'script': "1+doc['scores.year'].value"}}, 
 {'weight': 2.0, 'script_score': {'script': "1+doc['scores.month'].value"}}]
```

What's happening when I run this query? Are documents being scored by function_score and then sorted after the fact with the `sort` array? What is `_score` now (note that query is `match_all`) and does it do anything in the sorting? If I reversed it and put `time` before `_score` in sort, what result should I be expecting?

Comment: This sounds like something is not working as you would expect, but you don't ask about the problem rather you ask about what your query should actually do. Do you have an issue with the query above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `match_all` will give the same score without `function_score`, meaning each doc gets `1`.

With `function_score` it will compute all three scores (all three matches because you have no filter for each function) and it will multiply them (because you have `score_mode: multiply`). So, roughly you'll get `function1_score * function2_score * function3_score` final score. The resulting score will be used in the sort. In case some _scores are equal then the `time` is used in sorting.

**The best for you will be if you take out your query from your application, but it in JSON in Marvel's Sense dashboard for example and test it with `?explain`. It will give you detailed explanations for each computation of scores.**

Let me give you an example: let's say we have a document containing `"year":2015,"month":7,"time":"2015-07-06"`.

Running your query with `_search?explain` gives this very detailed explanation:

```
  "hits": [
     {
        "_shard": 4,
        "_node": "jt4AX7imTECLWH4Bofbk3g",
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "test",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 26691.023,
        "_source": {
           "text": "whatever",
           "year": 2015,
           "month": 7,
           "time": "2015-07-06"
        },
        "sort": [
           26691.023,
           1436140800000
        ],
        "_explanation": {
           "value": 26691.023,
           "description": "function score, product of:",
           "details": [
              {
                 "value": 1,
                 "description": "ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(year:[1990 TO *]) -cache(month:[13 TO *]))), product of:",
                 "details": [
                    {
                       "value": 1,
                       "description": "boost"
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 1,
                       "description": "queryNorm"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "value": 26691.023,
                 "description": "Math.min of",
                 "details": [
                    {
                       "value": 26691.023,
                       "description": "function score, score mode [multiply]",
                       "details": [
                          {
                             "value": 0.2758249,
                             "description": "function score, product of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 1,
                                   "description": "match filter: *:*"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value": 0.2758249,
                                   "description": "product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 0.055164978,
                                         "description": "Function for field time:",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 0.055164978,
                                               "description": "exp(-0.5*pow(MIN[Math.max(Math.abs(1.4361408E12(=doc value) - 1.437377331833E12(=origin))) - 0.0(=offset), 0)],2.0)/2.63856688924644672E17)"
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 5,
                                         "description": "weight"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "value": 6048,
                             "description": "function score, product of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 1,
                                   "description": "match filter: *:*"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value": 6048,
                                   "description": "product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 2016,
                                         "description": "script score function, computed with script:\"1+doc['year'].value",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "_score: ",
                                               "details": [
                                                  {
                                                     "value": 1,
                                                     "description": "ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(year:[1990 TO *]) -cache(month:[13 TO *]))), product of:",
                                                     "details": [
                                                        {
                                                           "value": 1,
                                                           "description": "boost"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                           "value": 1,
                                                           "description": "queryNorm"
                                                        }
                                                     ]
                                                  }
                                               ]
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 3,
                                         "description": "weight"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             "value": 16,
                             "description": "function score, product of:",
                             "details": [
                                {
                                   "value": 1,
                                   "description": "match filter: *:*"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value": 16,
                                   "description": "product of:",
                                   "details": [
                                      {
                                         "value": 8,
                                         "description": "script score function, computed with script:\"1+doc['month'].value",
                                         "details": [
                                            {
                                               "value": 1,
                                               "description": "_score: ",
                                               "details": [
                                                  {
                                                     "value": 1,
                                                     "description": "ConstantScore(BooleanFilter(+cache(year:[1990 TO *]) -cache(month:[13 TO *]))), product of:",
                                                     "details": [
                                                        {
                                                           "value": 1,
                                                           "description": "boost"
                                                        },
                                                        {
                                                           "value": 1,
                                                           "description": "queryNorm"
                                                        }
                                                     ]
                                                  }
                                               ]
                                            }
                                         ]
                                      },
                                      {
                                         "value": 2,
                                         "description": "weight"
                                      }
                                   ]
                                }
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    },
                    {
                       "value": 3.4028235e+38,
                       "description": "maxBoost"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "value": 1,
                 "description": "queryBoost"
              }
           ]
        }
     }
```

So, for `gauss` the score computed is 0.055164978. I don't know how relevant this is for your question, but let's assume the computation is correct :-). Your `gauss` function `weight` is 5, so the score becomes  5 * 0.055164978 = 0.27582489.

For the `script` `year` function we have (1 + 2015) * 3 = 6048.

For the `script` `month` function we have (1 + 7) * 2 = 16.

The total being `multiply` the total score for this document is 0.27582489 * 6048 * 16 = 26691.023

There is, also, a section for each document that shows what values were used for sorting. In this document's case:

```
        "sort": [
           26691.023,
           1436140800000
        ]
```

The first number is the `_score` computed as shown, the second is the milliseconds representation of date `2015-07-06`.